# How to bind a Map Interface with ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I am a Ember beginner and I have a question about data binding.
I have a complex data structure receifed from my Rest service. This structure is based on a Map interface and looks like this:

```
{"item":[
    {"name":"namlasteditor","value":["tom"]},
    {"name":"_subject","value":["Hello World"]},
    {"name":"type","value":["workitem"]}
]}
```

My application can not be sure which elements are contained in the map structure. So I can not simple map each element to a separate property.

Now my question is, how can I bind a value of a named item element to an input text in my template by a getter method? 
I am looking for somthing like:

{{input type="text" value=mydata.item('_subject')}}

But I can not figure out how to do this and if this is possible.
Can anybody give me a hint or an example how a ember model object should look look to get this problem solved?

I made some progress with the Ember.Handlebars.helper contsturct. But this was only usable to display a value of my map. A binding was not possible with the Ember.Handlebars.helper construct.